# My company has no letterhead, but Singapore requires one for proof of employment. How can I get around this?

Tags: visas, paperwork, singapore, applications

The Singapore visa application for an Indian citizen requires an NOC certificate. I currently work in a start up and there is no official letterhead. A travel agency that I contacted told me that the letterhead is mandatory. How should I go about this?

Comment: Note : The travel agency through which I applied (Thomas Cook) asked for a copy of my work ID card on looking at my application.

Comment: Nope. I work at an incubator and had the ID card they issued me. What should one do if he/she doesn't have ID?

Comment: Yeah. Two of them had a difference of opinion

Answer (score 2):

Startups are famously flexible in the way things are done, which in your case is a good thing. It will only take twenty minutes for someone in your HR Department to prepare a letterhead for your purpose.

Note that in Singapore, *it is [mandatory](https://companysecretary.me/2015/02/11/singapore-company-incorporation-registration-formation-establishment-a-step-by-step-guide/)  to mention the company registration number (UEN No.) on invoices and letterheads and other official stationery of the Company, if any*.

A sample of a NOC can be found [here](http://esampleletters.com/visa/noc-letter-format-from-employer-for-visa/)

Make sure you get the authority of someone in responsible for HR/Administration to sign off on the paperwork.